# Saving iteratively to a new DataFrame in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm performing computations based on 3 different PySpark DataFrames.

This script works in the sense that it performs the computation as it should, however, I struggle with working properly with the results of said computation.

```python
import sys
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext("local")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Dummy Data
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[0,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]], ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5'])
df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+
| p1| p2| p3| p4| p5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  1|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+

# Values
values = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(0,1,'p1'),(None,1,'p2'),(0,0,'p3'),(None,0, 'p4'),(1,None,'p5')], ('f1', 'f2','index'))
values.show()
+----+----+-----+
|  f1|  f2|index|
+----+----+-----+
|   0|   1|   p1|
|null|   1|   p2|
|   0|   0|   p3|
|null|   0|   p4|
|   1|null|   p5|
+----+----+-----+

# Weights
weights = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(4,3,'p1'),(None,1,'p2'),(2,2,'p3'),(None, 3, 'p4'),(3,None,'p5')], ('f1', 'f2','index'))
weights.show()
+----+----+-----+
|  f1|  f2|index|
+----+----+-----+
|   4|   3|   p1|
|null|   1|   p2|
|   2|   2|   p3|
|null|   3|   p4|
|   3|null|   p5|
+----+----+-----+

# Function: it sums the vector W for the values of Row equal to the value of V and then divide by the length of V.
# If there a no similarities between Row and V outputs 0
def W_sum(row,v,w):
    if len(w[row==v])>0:
        return float(np.sum(w[row==v])/len(w))
    else:
        return 0.0
```

For each of the columns and for each row in Data, the above function is applied.

```python
# We iterate over the columns of Values (except the last one called index)
for val in values.columns[:-1]:
    # we filter the data to work only with the columns that are defined for the selected Value
    defined_col = [i[0] for i in values.where(F.col(val) >= 0).select(values.index).collect()]
    # we select only the useful columns
    df_select= df.select(defined_col)
    # we retrieve the reference value and weights
    V = np.array(values.where(values.index.isin(defined_col)).select(val).collect()).flatten()
    W = np.array(weights.where(weights.index.isin(defined_col)).select(val).collect()).flatten()
    W_sum_udf = F.udf(lambda row: W_sum(row, V, W), FloatType())
    df_select.withColumn(val, W_sum_udf(F.array(*(F.col(x) for x in df_select.columns))))
```

This gives :

```python
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| p1| p2| p3| p4| p5| f1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|2.0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  1|1.0|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|2.0|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|0.0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|0.0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

It added the column to the sliced DataFrame as I asked it to. The problem is that I would rather collect the data into a new one that I could access at the end to consult the results.
It it possible to grow (somewhat efficiently) a DataFrame in PySpark as I would with pandas?

**Edit to make my goal clearer:**
Ideally I would get a DataFrame with the just the computed columns, like this:

```python
    +---+---+
    | f1| f2|
    +---+---+
    |2.0|1.0|
    |1.0|2.0|
    |2.0|0.0|
    |0.0|0.0|
    |0.0|2.0|
    +---+---+
```

Comment: Dataframes in spark are immutable. You will have to create a new dataframe for each row and apply union with the previous dataframe resulting in a new one with row 'appended'.

Comment: What exactly is your question (preferably with an example of the desired output)??

Comment: @desertnaut: I edited, hopefully my aim is clearer now.

Comment: `df_select` is nowhere defined; is it the same with `subsubsample`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your question...

First, your `for` loop will produce an error, since `df_select` in the last line is nowhere defined; there is also no assignment at the end (what does it produce?).

*Assuming* that `df_select` is actually your `subsubsample` dataframe, defined some lines before, and that your last line is something like

```python
new_df = subsubsample.withColumn(val, W_sum_udf(F.array(*(F.col(x) for x in subsubsample.columns))))
```

then your problem starts getting more clear. Since

```python
values.columns[:-1]
#  ['f1', 'f2']
```

the result of the whole loop would be just

```python
+---+---+---+---+---+ 
| p1| p2| p3| p4| f2| 
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  0|  0|1.0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|2.0|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|0.0|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|0.0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|2.0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

i.e. with only the column `f2` included (natural, since the results with `f1` are simply overwritten).

Now, as I said, *assuming* that the situation is like this, and that your problem is actually how to have both columns `f1` & `f2` together rather in different dataframes, you can just forget `subsubsample` and append columns to your initial `df`, possibly dropping afterwards the unwanted ones:

```python
init_cols = df.columns
init_cols
#  ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5']

new_df = df

for val in values.columns[:-1]:
    # we filter the data to work only with the columns that are defined for the selected Value
    defined_col = [i[0] for i in values.where(F.col(val) >= 0).select(values.index).collect()]
    # we retrieve the reference value and weights
    V = np.array(values.where(values.index.isin(defined_col)).select(val).collect()).flatten()
    W = np.array(weights.where(weights.index.isin(defined_col)).select(val).collect()).flatten()
    W_sum_udf = F.udf(lambda row: W_sum(row, V, W), FloatType())
    new_df = new_df.withColumn(val, W_sum_udf(F.array(*(F.col(x) for x in defined_col)))) # change here

# drop initial columns:
for i in init_cols:
  new_df = new_df.drop(i)
```

The resulting `new_df` will be:

```python
+---+---+ 
| f1| f2| 
+---+---+
|2.0|1.0| 
|1.0|2.0|
|2.0|0.0|
|0.0|0.0|
|0.0|2.0|
+---+---+
```

UPDATE (after comment): To force the division in your `W_sum` function to be a float, use:

```python
from __future__ import division
```

`new_df` now will be:

```python
+---------+----+ 
|       f1|  f2|
+---------+----+ 
|      2.0| 1.5|
|1.6666666|2.25|
|2.3333333|0.75|
|      0.0|0.75|
|0.6666667|2.25|
+---------+----+
```

with `f2` exactly as it should be according to your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this helped me a lot. One last thing, the results are truncated (f2 ought to be 1.5, 2.25, 0.75, 0.75, 2.25) is there any way around that?

Comment: @Haboryme didn't go through the details of your UDF at all; I focused exclusively to the columns appending part, which the question was about, and I have arguably replicated exactly your desired output. Nevertheless, see update...

Comment: awesome! Thanks.